# position of inline-block divs gets messed up as they get a new child

Tags: html, css

I am positioning 3 divs next to each other by setting their display to `inline-block`.
The problem is when I add a new element to any of the divs, their position gets messed up as you can see below.

why does this happens and what is the solution?

```css
*{
  border:none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}

.container{
  background-color:gray;
  height:100px;
  width:100%
}

.f1{
  background-color:red;
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:20%
}

.f2{
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:58%
}

.f3{
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:20%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="f1"></div>
  <div class="f2">
    <p> blah blah </p>
  </div>
  <div class="f3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want the *why* check the duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `display:flex;` or `float:left;` to solve this.

```css
* {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}

.container {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.f1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%
}

.f2 {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%
}

.f3 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="f1"></div>
  <div class="f2">
    <p> blah blah </p>
  </div>
  <div class="f3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code ..
css

```
*{
  border:none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}

.container{
  background-color:gray;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.f1{
  background-color:red;

  height:100%;
  width:20%
}

.f2{
  background-color:green;

  height:100%;
  width:60%
}

.f3{
  background-color:blue;

  height:100%;
  width:20%
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="f1"></div>
  <div class="f2">
    <p> blah blah </p>
  </div>
  <div class="f3"></div>
</di
```

Answer (score 0):

Try float:left  for left div, float:right, and then either margin : auto or text-align: center for the middle div

Answer (score 0):

Also the left:0px and right:0px property might work as well for your situation if you are using that display property.